# Cauchy's Homogenous Linear Equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Solve the differential Equation(Find the complete solution i.e., Complete Solution = Particular Integral + Complementary Function)
$$
x^{2} \frac{d^{2} y}{d x^{2}}+3 x \frac{d y}{d x}+y=\frac{1}{(1-x)^{2}}
$$

Answer Given for the above problem is
$$
y=\frac{1}{x}\left(c_{1} \log x+c_{2}\right)+\frac{1}{x} \log \frac{x}{1-x}
$$
My attempt:

Fisrt I substituted $$
x=e^{t}
$$
Then converted the above Differential equation to A Linear Differential Equation$$
(D+1)^{2} y=\frac{1}{\left(1-e^{t}\right)^{2}}
$$
And wrote Particular Integral as$$
\text { P.I. }=\frac{1}{(D+1)^{2}} \times \frac{1}{\left(1-e^{t}\right)^{2}}
$$

(Here D=$\frac{d}{dt}$)

and on further solving I got P.I equal to$$
x^{-2} \log \left|\frac{1}{1-x}\right|
$$

I don't know where I am wrong!. And I also don't know if the answer given above is also correct or not.

Comment: You can easily integrate the ODE. Rewrite it as  :$$(x^2y')'+(xy)'=\dfrac {1}{(x-1)^2}$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\text { P.I. }=\frac{1}{(D+1)^{2}}  \frac{1}{\left(1-e^{t}\right)^{2}}$$
$$\text { P.I. }=\frac{1}{(D+1)^{2}}  \frac{e^{-t}}{e^{-t}\left(1-e^{t}\right)^{2}}$$
Now apply the rule:
$$\dfrac 1 D e^{at}V(t)=e^{at}\dfrac 1 {D+a}V(t)$$
$$\text { P.I. }=e^{-t}\frac{1}{D^{2}}  \frac{e^t}{\left(1-e^{t}\right)^{2}}$$
Then the integral is easy:
$$\frac{1}{D}  \frac{e^t}{\left(1-e^{t}\right)^{2}}=\int \dfrac {du}{(1-u)^2}=-\dfrac 1 {u-1}$$
Where $u=e^t$. Integrate again.
$$\frac{1}{D^{2}}  \frac{e^t}{\left(1-e^{t}\right)^{2}}=-\ln |u-1|$$

You get:
$$\text {PI}=-e^{-t}\ln |e^{t}-1|=-\dfrac 1 x \ln \left| {x-1} \right | $$

---

Note that the answer given
$$y=\frac{1}{x}\left(c_{1} \log x+c_{2}\right)+\frac{1}{x} \log \frac{x}{1-x}$$
is just
$$y=\frac{1}{x}\left(c \log x+c_{2}\right)-\frac{1}{x} \log |{x-1}|$$
Since $\dfrac {\log x}x$ is absorbed by the solution to the homogeneos DE.

Comment: I don't understand how you wrote (D+1)^2=D^2?

Comment: I added an exponential at the denominator @UditChauhan

Comment: I added some lines is it more clear @UditChauhan

Comment: SORRY, but i think your answer is not correct, in term inside 'log' there is also a 'x' in the numerator.

Comment: But compute the log in the answer you are given some part of the log is absorbed by the solution to the homogeneous differntial equation...My Answer agree with the given answer. Its just more simple. @UditChauhan

Comment: I added more lines at the end that shows that both answers are equivalents; @UditChauhan